# Cannot create SSL Engine: The target principle name is incorrect, SSL and SAP HANA

Tags: ssl, self-signed-certificate, ssl-certificate-errors, sap-hana

I'm getting the following error when attempting to connect to a tenant database in a multi-tenant SAP HANA Server running on SUSE Linux:

[image]

I can connect via SSL to the system database of the HANA server, and the server's certificate was created on the system server. Therefore, I think the problem is that the "principal name" of the system database differs from the principle name of the tenant database. Since the tenant database inherited all the SSL-related properties form the system database, the client can't validate the tenant database's certificate because the tenant database != the server database. However, I'm not sure how to compare the "principle names" of two servers. Can someone give me more information on what a principle name is, and how I might go about resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the DATABASENAME connection property. When that property is used, the hostname:port of the system database that gets included in the connection string is used for hostname verification with the tenant database. Since the tenant DB connects to the host on a different port, the certificate validation portion of the SSL connection fails.